# Setting default values for Design tab in Product Information in Magento admin

Tags: magento

I was wondering, is it possible to set default values for the Design tab of a product in the dashboard in Magento admin. By default, this is how the design tab looks:

[image]

Given this, I find it quite tedious to have to repeatedly select the design and page layout every time I add a new product. So, is there any way I can set this to the option I use most for products? Also, I'd like to hide Active From, Active To and Custom Layout Update if it's possible.

Comment: So, you want default image for most of the product? Otherwise, you want to add new image, you can add image on based on each product?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you right. I'd like to set Custom Design and Page Layout with a default value, like 2-columns left and modern

Comment: @user1597438, when you vote for any answer also mark as correct so that any other user can get help.

Comment: I thought their question was more general... like, any time you create a new thing in magento (eg, new category, new product, new catalog price rule (aka "coupon"), how do you configure it so that certain.. attributes for lack of a better word.. are pre-configured so that whomever non-technical user of the admin panel doesn't have to configure these fields every time... presuming that we'll always be configuring these things the same way that is..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to one design to all product, then you can set it from `app\design\frontend\YOUR_TEMPLATE_PATH\default\layout\catalog.xml`.

From this xml you can set template. Search for `<catalog_product_view translate="label">` and under this node you will find template settings.

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

So, you want default image for most of the product? Otherwise, you want to add new image, you can add image on based on each product?
If you want based on upper description, Go to 
    `System->Configuration`

Under `Catalog` tab and Click on `Catalog` Menu link and Go to `Product Image Place Holders`. You can set there for default image. If you add new product image on each product, new image override to this default image.See picture

![image]

Hope help :)